# Type '<T>' is not assignable to type '<V>'. Index signature is missing in type '<T>'

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I am trying to enable strictTemplate in my angular codebase and am facing some issues when I am creating my types.

I have the following models:

```
export class User {
   public 'name'!: Filter<string>;
   public 'email'!: Filter<string>;
   public 'age':!: Filter<number>
}

export class Engine {
   public 'weight'!: Filter<number>;
   public 'isRunning'!: Filter<boolean>;
}

export class Filter<T> {
  public 'value'!: T;
  public 'isSortedAscending'?: boolean;
}
```

This is the class that has the the input where Engine or User will eventually be passed:

```
@Component(
   selector: 'app-table',
   templateUrl: './table.component.html',
)
export class TableComponent 
{
   @Input()
   public sort: TableSortModel

   ....Omitted details for simplicity
}

export class  TableSortModel {
  [key: string]: Filter<unknown>;
}
```

Please take into consideration that Engine or User are not the only models that I am passing in my appplication, there are others but they all have properties which have there types defined to Filter.

I receive the following errors:

> Type 'Engine' is not assignable to type 'TableSortModel '.
> Index signature is missing in type 'Engine'.

> Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'TableSortModel '.
> Index signature is missing in type 'User'.

Now I am asuming index signature is refering to  [key: string]: Filter.

My question is what should my TableSortModel look like so I can be able to pass both of the classes I mentioned above?

Comment: You'll have to add the index signature to the `User` and `Engine` types.

Comment: From the compiler's point of view, it's probably thinking that having an index signature on your class means that _any_ key property is acceptable including the properties you have explicitly defined in the class.

Comment: I guess you could try making the `Engine` and `User` classes extend from the `TableSortModel` class then, or you could try updating your `TableSortModel` class such that the index signature is nullable.

Answer (score 0):

Using interfaces works out.

```
export class Filter<T> {
  public "value"!: T;
  public "isSortedAscending"?: boolean;
}

export interface User extends TableSortModel {
  name: Filter<string>;
  email: Filter<string>;
  age: Filter<number>;
}

export interface Engine extends TableSortModel {
  weight: Filter<number>;
  isRunning: Filter<boolean>;
}

export interface TableSortModel {
  [index: string]: Filter<unknown>;
}
```

Demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tnrss5?file=src/app/index.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  item: TableSortModel;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.item = {
      age: new Filter<number>()
    } as User;
  }
}
```

```
export class SortDemoComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  public sort: TableSortModel;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```